# ASP Repeater Not Updating After Databind

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, updatepanel, repeater

Kind of a complicated question, but I have a custom user control ("roster list") which contains an ASP Repeater. This control has a method called RefreshRosterList that gets called on Page_Load of the control. This control gets dynamically inserted into an UpdatePanel.

The master page contains two update panels - one for my roster list, one for other controls.

I have a separate control that causes a postback. This control ("merge courses") inserts a new record into a database and calls my RefreshRosterList method.

At the end of my RefreshRosterList method is a call to databind my Repeater with new data. I know the data is correct when it binds to the Repeater.

I say it's not updating, but I've figured out the Repeater will show the new item if I commit a second post back. What I mean by that is if I create a merge of CIS161-01 and CIS161-02 called CIS161, it won't show. After that's merged, if I create a second merge of CIS171-01 and CIS171-02 called CIS171, that's when the CIS161 merge will show but the CIS171 merge will not.

How can I get my first merge to show on databind?

I hope this makes sense. I can try to provide whatever code necessary, but it's spread out over many different files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the control as a trigger of the update panel the roster list is in or trigger the update yourself.

Comment: Can I set the control as a trigger for an UpdatePanel it's not in? If so, how would I go about doing that?
  
Edit: I've also tried finding the UpdatePanel using FindControl() and calling it's Update() method, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried this?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx

Comment: Yes, I have the following in my the page load event on my merge control.

    `ScriptManager sm = (ScriptManager)Page.Master.FindControl("ScriptManager1");`
    `sm.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(btnMerge);`